# JS Func. logs message with time interval

Tags: javascript

Was hoping to find some help complete this question.

logs the message parameter to the console every (Number Parameter). Implement an html button to start and stop this sequence.

In attempting the question I was able to get this so far.

```
  var displayLog  = function Container(param) {

      var message = 'any string'; // Local message variable
      var timeCount = "10"; // Local time count variable

       setInterval(function getLoggeddemo(message,timeCount) {
       console.log(message);
       return getLoggeddemo;
       }(), timeCount);
  }
```

The question is asking to display a message every (x) seconds, when a button is toggled between start & stop. I'm currently trying to figure out how to include an if/else statement to start and stop the sequence with an Html button .

Comment: setInterval and clearInterval (this would stop logging).

Comment: thankyou just need a little clarification do I place function that clears the interval after it is set like clearInterval(function (){ })

Comment: Also would you know how to start and stop this with an html button, I would probably use an if/else statement right? Want to make sure I'm on the right road according to the question

Comment: Take a look at clearInterval here - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp. Also, how to attach click event handler to button here - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues:

- Don't call the function you want to pass to to `setInterval`: so remove the parentheses after the function body.
- You never seem to call `displayLog`.
- `timeCount` is supposed to be a number, not a string: it is the number of milliseconds the interval lasts.
- There is no influence of the button clicks on the interval logic.
- Returning something in a `setInterval` callback has no meaning. Also the arguments will not be provided to that callback: remove those parameters.

I would suggest not to add/remove event listeners, but to use a boolean variable that indicates the state you are in, and depending on that perform the appropriate action in one, single click handler:

```js
var i = 0;
var displayLog = function Container(message) {
    console.log(i++, message);
    // Return the id of the interval
    return setInterval(function getLoggeddemo() { // no arguments here
        console.log(i++, message);
    }, 1000); // Every second
} 

var mixBut = document.getElementById("mixBut");
var interval = null;
mixBut.addEventListener("click", toggle);

function toggle(){
    if (interval === null) {
        mixBut.value = "Stop";
        interval = displayLog("Hi there!");
    } else {
        mixBut.value = "Start";
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = null;
    }
}
```

```html
<button id="mixBut">Mix</button>
```